# Solr search getting different scrore of products with OR condtion in query

Tags: solr

We are facing problem with query where we are using multiple 'OR' conditions to search products from solr documents

below is our searching condition with "OR"

```
<str name="q">(product_related_kword:(leather AND shopping AND bags)) OR (product_related_kword:(paper AND shopping AND bags))</str>
```

here we are searching for tow products "leather shopping bags" && "paper shopping bags"

Now we got the result like this

```
<str name="product_name">leather Paper shopping bag</str>
<float name="score">58.45</float></doc>

<str name="product_name">Paper shopping bag</str>
<float name="score">56.45</float></doc>

<str name="product_name">leather shopping bags</str>
<float name="score">56.45</float></doc>
```

why we got different 'score' for the product in top "leather Paper shopping bag"

i want equal score for the search results if matched in the document with 'OR' condition

Comment: It's because all the 4 words matches and hence it gets higher score..try matching phrase...or use dismax

Comment: Appending `debug=all` to your query will give you information about exactly how the score is being calculated and what terms contribute what to the end score.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dismax here. The dismax comes with many params and one of them is phrase fields.

> The pf (Phrase Fields) Parameter Once the list of matching documents
> has been identified using the fq and qf parameters, the pf parameter
> can be used to "boost" the score of documents in cases where all of
> the terms in the q parameter appear in close proximity.
>
> The format is the same as that used by the qf parameter: a list of
> fields and "boosts" to associate with each of them when making phrase
> queries out of the entire q parameter.

You can read more about dismax [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-dismax-query-parser.html)

> The mm (Minimum Should Match) Parameter When processing queries,
> Lucene/Solr recognizes three types of clauses: mandatory, prohibited,
> and "optional" (also known as "should" clauses). By default, all words
> or phrases specified in the q parameter are treated as "optional"
> clauses unless they are preceded by a "+" or a "-". When dealing with
> these "optional" clauses, the mm parameter makes it possible to say
> that a certain minimum number of those clauses must match. The DisMax
> query parser offers great flexibility in how the minimum number can be
> specified.